# String localization: getMessage

Tags: spring, spring-boot

**Code**

```
Locale locale = new Locale(Language.LANG, "");
String baseName = "i18n/messages";

ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
ResourceBundle messages= ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName, locale);
String value = messages.getString("greeting"); // Working


String value1 = messageSource.getMessage("greeting", null, locale); // Exception.
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'greeting' for locale 'ru'.
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:161)
    at ru.pcask.AdsmanagerApplication.main(AdsmanagerApplication.java:102)
```

**Problem**

`messages.getString("greeting")`is  working perfectly. But I'd like to use getMessage or something where I can use locale in the method rather than setting it beforehand.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You are doing a `getMessage` on an empty `ResourceBundleMessageSource` so ofcourse it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

you can use MessageSource and call getMessage(String s, Object[] obj, Locale locale)

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

String message = messageSource.getMessage("greeting", obj, locale);
```

Comment: I can't understand you. What is the difference between your wariant and my faulty one? I can't see anything. Obj is an argument here to the message. I don't need it if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Did you create the "greeting" String in message_ru.properties file. you can refer to it here https://www.baeldung.com/java-localization-messages-formatting. ResourceBundle is not able to fetch the greeting String for "ru" locale

Comment: The answer is not correct, just repeating method signature